# Retrofit : NPE , attempt to invoke interface method on null object reference (Release version only)

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I am new to Retrofit, My implementation works just fine in the debug version of my app but as soon as I switch to a release build I get a NPE when invoking the model class (My POJO class). I made sure in Proguard I add

```
-keep class retrofit.** { *; }
-keep class retrofit.http.** { *; }
-keep class retrofit.client.** { *; }
-keep class com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-keep interface com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-keepattributes Signature
-dontwarn okio.**
```

Here is my Retorfit implementation:

> ```
>     TestService service = RequestHelper.createService(TestAPIService.class,
>      TestAPIService.BASE_URL);
>
>                     service.getResponse("USER", 40, new Callback<OffersResponse>() {
>
>
>                         @Override
>                         public void success(final TestResponse testResponse, final Response response) {
>
>                             bundle.putParcelable("TestResponse", testResponse);
>                             String user = testResponse.getUser().get(0).getName().toString();
>                             Toast.makeText(getActivity(),user, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
>
>                         }
>
>                         @Override
>                         public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
>                             Log.d(TAG, "" + error.toString());
>
>                         }
>                     });
> ```

The debug version gives me the correct user name and in the release version I get the correct response from the server in the logs but when i try to show a toast with user name I get a NPE `Attempt to invoke interface method on a null object reference`

complete stack trace

```
E/AndroidRuntime(17647): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object java.util.List.get(int)' on a null object reference
E/AndroidRuntime(17647):    at com.test.browser.check.w.a(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime(17647):    at com.test.browser.check.w.success(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime(17647):    at retrofit.CallbackRunnable$1.run(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime(17647):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
E/AndroidRuntime(17647):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
E/AndroidRuntime(17647):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
E/AndroidRuntime(17647):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
E/AndroidRuntime(17647):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(17647):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
E/AndroidRuntime(17647):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
E/AndroidRuntime(17647):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
W/ActivityManager( 2144):   Force finishing activity com.test.browser/.check.Check
```

Comment: What was the actual stack trace? That will help figuring out what has been obfuscated/removed by proguard.

Comment: I think I forgot to add my own SDK classes to the proguard properties.Trying it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All my POJO classes and server api calls are part of a library project (My own SDK). I forgot to add my SDK to proguard property file which caused the error. Everything working now.